# What are the best practices for programming the behaviors of the scenario elements in a point and click game?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I'm starting a game in the style of tiny thief using iOS7 sprite kit. I am wondering whats the best way to approach the logic programming for the different scenario elements, I wonder is there is some optimized way to get the character moving though different floor levels and other elements like ladders or stairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that won't be appropriate to use, normally create a cclayer object and start coding it. No need to create the whole view in tiles

Comment: Thanks, can you please give me some orientation on how to manage the mentioned scenario elements ? I can imagine how to program it based on the coordinates  but this  would be rather hideous, I was wondering if there are some techniques more appropriate for this?

Comment: ok fine but i think the conversation here would create some negative impression in stack overflow. Lets have a chat somewhere else, Facebook or Skype anywhere you have a account